# Получить значение свойства объекта в объекте, используя деструктуризацию. ES6

Tags: javascript

Дан объект:

```
let o = {
    obj: {
        a: 1,
    },
};
```

Как с помощью деструктуризации сразу получить значение свойства а?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Детальнее](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#%D0%92%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82_%D0%B8_%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80_%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0)

```js
const o = {
    obj: {
        a: 1,
    },
};

const {
  obj: {
    a
  }
} = o;

console.log(a);
```